# jQuery countdown with update

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

We are using the following countdown function on our bidding site.

```
setInterval(function(){
        $(".countdown").each(function(){
            var seconds = $(this).data('seconds');
            if(seconds > 0) {
                second = seconds - 1;
                $(this).data('seconds', second)
                 var date = new Date(null);
                 date.setSeconds(second); 
                 $(this).html(date.toISOString().substr(11, 8))
            }
          else
            {
              $(this).html("Finished");
    alert('finished');
            }
        });
    }, 1000);
```

we pass the number of seconds where we want the counter to appear (sometimes more than once on our page:

```
echo "<div id=\"".$auctionid."\" class=\"countdown\" data-seconds=\"".$diff."\"></div>";
```

So far it should be clear an it works. Now we have a situation where when someone bids somewhere on the site - the time left for auction is prolonged for 15 seconds, which is written to mysql.

$diff variable is calculated from mysql end time, and it's passed to jQuery on page load.

The question is how to check the mysql time for that auction and sync it in jQuery counter? We had the idea to maybe check every 5 seconds and after it reaches zero to make sure it's over? Any suggestions?

It should look nice to the user.

EDIT:

This is what we have so far:

```
$(".countdown").each(function() {

        var countdown = $(this);
        var auctionid = $(this).attr('id');

            var interval = setInterval(function() {

                        var seconds = countdown.data("seconds");

                        if( seconds > 0 ) {

                            var second = --seconds;
                            var date = new Date(null);
                            date.setSeconds(second);
                            countdown.data("seconds", second).html(date.toISOString().substr(11, 8))

                        } else {

                        //      countdown.html("Finished <img src=\"loading.gif\" class=\"tempload\">");

                            startUpdateingTimeFromDatabase(auctionid);

                            countdown.html("Finished");
                            clearInterval(interval);

                        }

            }, 1000);

});





function startUpdateingTimeFromDatabase(auctionid) {


            $.getJSON("timer.php?auctionid="+auctionid, function(response) { 
                // console.log(response.seconds); 

                    $(".countdown#"+auctionid).data("seconds", response.seconds);

                    if( response.seconds > 0 ) {
                        //  setTimeout(startUpdateingTimeFromDatabase(auctionid), 1000);
                    } else {

                    }

             });


}
```

This simply isn't doing what we need it to do. We need to update the seconds (query startUpdateingTimeFromDatabase) every time it reaches zero. Now I think there are two approaches. First is simply return seconds via startUpdateingTimeFromDatabase function and then do everything in the main function, second is update the div via startUpdateingTimeFromDatabase. I think first will be better but I simply can't find a way to do it properly.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Not solving your problem right now, but I have an improvement for you. Not loop all countdowns in the setInterval. Just create the intervals once within the loop and you're done. This would prevent the on-and-on search vor the elements each second. For example: https://jsfiddle.net/rwd23ooz/1/

Comment: ok, that's useful. one idea i had was to simply sync the timer once it reaches zero?

Comment: Save the actual deadline in a js variable and check after every 5 iterations/seconds to see if the time is aligned. No need for ajax requests in this case.

Comment: it needs to be double checked from mysql at every 00 counter since it might be updated in mysql in the meantime.

Answer (score 1):

You store the seconds left in the elements `data`. So why not fetch the remaining time maybe via `ajax` and just pass the new seconds to the elements? Within the next interval run all times will be updated.

Something like this:

```
$.get("yourGetRemainingTimeScript.php", {auctionId: 1}, function(response) {
    $(".countdown").data("seconds", response.seconds);
});
```

How you check and get the remaining time is up to you. You can set the time for all everywhere again.

```
$(".countdown").data("seconds", 1337);
```

---

Another hint from my side: don't loop all elements with `each` in the `setInterval`. Create the intervals inside the loop once. Then your script doesn't need to search every second again over and over for the elements.

And clear the interval when it's finished.

```
$(".countdown").each(function() {
    var countdown = $(this);
    var interval = setInterval(function() {
        // do your stuff ...

        // when finished stop the interval
        if( finished ) {
            clearInterval(interval);
        }
    }, 1000);
});
```

[Full working example.](https://jsfiddle.net/rwd23ooz/5/)

Comment: Hello, I am stull trying this, but your fiddle is either incomplete or it doesn't do the trick - i tried adding <div id="552" class="countdown" data-seconds="90"></div> in html for testing , nothing happens

Comment: Sorry, that was only a demo, not a working example. :) I've updated it, see here: https://jsfiddle.net/rwd23ooz/4/

Comment: Ok that works, but what about mysql sync part. I tried your example with .get - not sure if I did it ok, but does that mean it reads from mysql every second? Can you please elaborate how to do this right?

Comment: yes, from what I see, if it's done with that get function that would fetch timer.php script each second to check time. Instead of that we need a better solution, maybe sync every X seconds or simply sync when it reach 0? Dunno - would like to hear your suggestion

Comment: You could create a timeout for the ajax request too. Like every X seconds. https://jsfiddle.net/rwd23ooz/7/ (please not the special request for jsfiddle, I explained this in the comments)

Comment: ok i implemented that but can't see that something is happening. i created timer.php with fixed result: {"seconds":45} - when is startUpdateingTimeFromDatabase actually triggered?

Comment: Take a look at the bottom of my example https://jsfiddle.net/rwd23ooz/7/. There i call `startUpdateingTimeFromDatabase` manually once. :)

Comment: Hello eisbehr, I have been trying to figure this out for few days already, without much success. Although the counter works flawlessly, the update does not. in the last try i created a simple timer.php with this code: $response["seconds"] = 45;
echo json_encode(array("seconds" => $response["seconds"]));
and it does nothing to the counter. Please help. thanks. Also, please check your GCC fb page messages.

Comment: When you call your `timer.php` manually, what is your response? It should be `{"seconds": 45}`, correct? Then your request should be like `$.get("timer.php", function(response) { console.log(response.seconds); });`. Is this working somehow? Are you getting any errors?

Comment: Yes, it is {"seconds":45} console log says : undefined

Comment: Could you try `$.getJSON` instead of `$.get`?

Comment: oh, I see. so now whatever I pass to timer.php is passed to the counter that calls the function? the only thing I see now is that (since we have multiple counters on one page) we need to pass the auctionid to startUpdateingTimeFromDatabase function - right?

Comment: Yes, you can pass the auctionId, like in my answer example. How to solve this is now up to you. Or creating a new question. I can't do your whole work now. ;)

Comment: Haha, yes, I agree. Thanks a lot for this so far. It's been very very helpful, you are really great!

Comment: Just one simple question. how should this look like in order to update the timer on zero and if it's ended show finish, else update clock? would this work?    } else {

     var left = startUpdateingTimeFromDatabase(auctionid);

     if( left < 0 ) {
      countdown.html("Finished");
      clearInterval(interval);
     } 

   }

Comment: you have this:    else {
    countdown.html("Finished");
    clearInterval(interval);
   } - I think it would be good to simply check when it reaches zero and update it then if necessary

Comment: the problem is that I am not doing something right https://jsfiddle.net/rwd23ooz/10/ - this is what I have now, and it's showing Finishedundefined for those that are over... the most preferable action would be to simply show the loader at 00.00.00, check the database and update if seconds left > 0 and show finished it otherwise